# Azure Ubuntu VM docker build apt-get 403 forbidden

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I'm trying to configure Docker on an Azure VM (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). The goal is to use Jenkins to deploy my applications to my Kubernetes cluster (following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/jenkins-continuous-deployment)).

But when I try to build a docker image inside this VM I got 403 errors during the "RUN apt-get update". While the VM itself can access those urls, it's only during the build of the docker image that I get 403 errors.

Sample of the output :

```
Err:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main all Packages
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted all Packages
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe all Packages
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse all Packages
Reading package lists...
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

I have found some similar questions like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/816900/ubuntu-apt-get-update-403-forbidden-in-docker-on-azure-vm) but none of the answers worked or explains exactly what happens in Azure (firewall or transparent proxy not used properly by the network of docker I guess).

Is there a specific configuration for docker, azure VM, ...?

Thank you.

Comment: The error shows the issue. It because the package resource cannot reach. You should change the source list.

Comment: Ok which source list should I use?

Comment: I tried mirrors for repositories and I also get 403 but I found a link between all 403 errors, it's  always amd64 packages which are forbidden with the mirrors

Comment: I mean the command `RUN apt-get update` run in the Docker base image, so you should try to change the source list of the base image. Not your VM. Take a try.